# Android Saving JSON response in Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

I have json response in string datatype. I want to save this text to sharedpreferences but it neither gives me error nor save it to sharedpreferences.
but when I try to retrieve it gives me empty value and null pointer exception if I fetch its length. MY JSON REPONE is at

http://www.professionalhub.pk/recipe/webServices/recipe1.php

Comment: where is your code and logcat???

Comment: what would i post from the logcat as i told you it doesnot gives me error.

Comment: if you want to store this long FULL JSON, then please use files for that, It's not good if you store this kind of full string in SharedPrefrence. Please try to store full JSON in file. and later you can retrive your full JSON response by reading that file. ! Please try to do that.

Comment: @Rahul can you specify a link for this purpose i am new to android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class for your purpose with files ! Hope it will help you !

```
 public class MyJSON {

        static String fileName = "myBlog.json";

        public static void saveData(Context context, String mJsonResponse) {
            try {
                FileWriter file = new FileWriter(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
                file.write(mJsonResponse);
                file.flush();
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error in Writing: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        public static String getData(Context context) {
            try {
                File f = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
                //check whether file exists
                FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                return new String(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error in Reading: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it took more time to read the file than fetching it online. i wanted to save this string so that user will not have to wait to populate the list.

Comment: Thank you its working perfectly. i was toasting the retrieved string from file thats why it was taking too much time. without toasting it loads in less than a second. Thank you once again Mr Rahul

Comment: You are welcome my dear friend ! You can accept and upvote my answer if it helped you !